# How to show/hide each element in v-loop by click?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a table with fields who should be available for editing.
For example:

```
<tr v-for="item in items">
     <td>
         //show by default and hide when edit button clicked
         <span>{{item.value}}</span>

         //show by click on edit button
         <b-input :value="item.value"></b-input>
     </td>

     <td>
         //edit button (show input field)
         <span class="icon is-small" v-on:click="">
            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
         </span>

         //save button (call function with axios)
         <span class="icon is-small" v-on:click="">
            <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
         </span>

         //loader (show until the axios request is complete)
         <span class="icon is-small">
            <i class="fa fa-pulse fa-spinner"></i>
         </span>
     </td>
</tr>
```

When I click to edit button I should get the input field and save button instead edit button. When I click to save button, I should send axios request and show loader spinner until the axios request is complete.
And I need to be able to show all inputs at the same time. I mean if I click to the next field for editing, previous input should be showing too. 
Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you can add some keys to `items` then you can do that :

```
<tr v-for="item in items">
     <td>
         //show by default and hide when edit button clicked
         <span v-if="!item.edit">{{item.value}}</span>

         //show by click on edit button
         <b-input :value="item.value" v-else></b-input>
     </td>

     <td>
         //edit button (show input field)
         <span class="icon is-small" v-on:click="handleEdit(item)" v-if="!item.edit">
            <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
         </span>

         //save button (call function with axios)
         <span class="icon is-small" v-on:click="handleSave(item)" v-else>
            <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
         </span>

         //loader (show until the axios request is complete)
         <span class="icon is-small" v-if="item.loading">
            <i class="fa fa-pulse fa-spinner"></i>
         </span>
     </td>
</tr>
```

```
export default {
  data() {
      return {
        items:[
          {
            value: foo,
            edit: false,
            loading: false
          },
          {
            value: bar,
            edit: false,
            loading: false
          }
        ]
      }
    },
  methods: {
    handleEdit(item) {
      item.edit = true
    },
    handleSave(item) {
      item.edit = false
      item.loading = true
      axios.post(url, params)
        .then(function(response) {
          item.loading = false
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          item.loading = false
        })
    }
  }
}
```